# Run two infinite processes concurrently

Tags: c, sockets, parallel-processing

I have programmed a simple Telephony application using Gstreamer. I use also a simple UDP sockets to do the signaling. Upon receiving a special message over UDP my Gstreamer shall start and do the transmission. 
Now there are two processes that shall initiate after signaling has been done:

**Process 1:** sending voice using Microphone ( which is always running until it is manually stopped

I use an executable file within signaling application to do this:

```
if(  ! strcmp(buf,"callee picked up ") ) system("/home/fereydoon/udpSender");
```

and `buf` is the msg received which is checked to see whether or not udpSender should be executed.

**Process 2:** Receiving and decoding incoming packages.

```
if(  ! strcmp(buf,"callee picked up ") ) system("/home/fereydoon/udpReceiver");
```

When i include the above code lines in my Signaling.c it continues to send UDP voice packages just fine, but the rest of the code(udpReceiver) is not executed until udpSender is stopped, which makes my telephony one-directional.
i need to to have my signaling.c start the receiving process as udpSender is being executed.
I suppose `system()` does not provide such a functionality. Is there any way to do this?

P.S: i am using Ubuntu **13.10 OS**

Comment: `system()` executes synchronously, blocking the calling thread.  You should fork a new process or create a distinct thread for the first `system` call (with `fork` you may prefer to `execv` the `udpSender` and/or ~`Receiver` rather than call `system()` which executes a shell then asks it to run your program).  (Alternatively, if the rest of your program operates at that high a level then you might get away with writing a shell script....)

Comment: What about multithreading or multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ampersand at the end of the system() calls.

```
system("/home/fereydoon/udpSender &");
```

EDIT: it must be paid attention that after the main application is stopped the udpSender Process is not killed and it has to be stopped manually or by adding kill processes to code.

Comment: Thank you very short and useful

Answer (score 1):

From how you have described the problem it sounds like you dont have two separate processes in the software sense of the work. Just two separate tasks. Your first task when executed blocks the thread of control when what you want is for both tasks to be run concurrently. There are a couple of ways to do this but the easiest is just to put both tasks in separate threads. Each thread will run concurrently and your two tasks will appear to be running at the same time.

You can learn more about threads in C++ here: http://codebase.eu/tutorial/posix-threads-c/

Comment: This is also a good approach but i am guessing adding that APERSAND at the end of System directory is much simpler

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that the `system` call is blocking. So, the execution stay block at the first call of `system`.

You have to use either [`fork`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29)  or [`pthreads`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) to parallelize your executions.

A simpler solution will be to start your executables in background using the `&`:

```
if(  ! strcmp(buf,"callee picked up ") ) system("/home/fereydoon/udpSender &");
if(  ! strcmp(buf,"callee picked up ") ) system("/home/fereydoon/udpReceiver &");
```